# What is the standard length for SATA cables?

Tags: sata, cable

Is there a standard length for a SATA cable?

If not, what are the most common lengths provided with motherboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#DATACONN,

> SATA cables can have lengths up to 1 metre (3.3 ft)

The two pretty much stock cables I currently have are both 50 cm (that includes the connectors; they were provided with a motherboard).

Comment: I don't really like the "IIRC" here, but It seem exactly that the standard is 0.5m (50cm). The second answer is also helpful but lack of this information.

Comment: @Had okay, maybe this will make you feel better about the "IIRC" part: they are (well, were, before I broke them out to measure) sealed in a simple plastic package consisting of two sealed pockets - the other has a power cable with 1 molex and 2 SATA power connectors. I only ever saw such packages come with motherboards. I recall that it must have been included with an [M3N-HD/HDMI](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M3NHDHDMI) motherboard we purchased a couple of years ago - we didn't unseal it because we didn't have any SATA HDDs at the time.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Seagate knowledge base](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/serial-ata-sata-data-cable-lengths-182453en/):

> Serial ATA cables are available in many lengths up to 1 meter. Minimum cable length is 12 inches [or 30 cm], using shorter cables can cause timing, or noise interference on the cable. The same conditions apply to cables that are too long. Though the Serial ATA specification calls out supporting cable lengths up to 1 meter or 39.37 inches, PCB traces from the cable connection to the host and drive controllers ASIC, adds length to the bus.
>
> Example: SATA drive installed with a 40 inch cable. PCB trace from Serial host connector to the serial hosts ASIC = 3 inches. The same 3 inch PCB trace applies to the hard disk. This configuration gives you a bus length of about 46 inches. If you are having performance or data corruption issues, try using a shorter cable or different manufacturer of cable. Cable quality can vary between vendors.

Comment: I have seen SATA cables between 1 foot and 2 feet.  Be aware of the connectors and the clearance between the drive/case.  Frequently I have to use a 90-degree connector instead of a straight connector because of tight clearances.  If you have to bend the cable sharply, just use a 90-degree connector.

Comment: "Between 1 ft and 2 ft"... which means 50 cm, a pretty standard length, apparently.  And min length is then, obviously, 30 cm, and *NOT* 12 inches.

Sheesh.  METRIC!  DO IT!